# What can I do the question "Is taking frequent breaks really that beneficial when programming?" to make it on-topic?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question

The question [Is taking frequent breaks really that beneficial when programming?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/16595/1130) got closed as off-topic today.

I feel this is a valid question for software developers, and that the answers provide some good advice to developers wondering the same thing. In fact, I saw a question today that was asking advice about what to do during the 5-10 minutes they took for a break, and I pointed them to the answers to this question.

So my question is, what can I do to this question to make it on-topic and get it re-opened?

Comment: WorkRave rules! ;)

Comment: Yes WorkRave can save your life

Answer (score 2):

Well, you'd have to revise the question to require the unique expertise of software developers. Of course it's a question relevant to software developers, but unfortunately that doesn't make it on topic. And you'd have to remove all the non constructive / list building ("Is that the same for you") elements.

It could be on topic (as is) at [Personal Productivity](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/), I could ask the Personal Productivity mods and you can also drop by their [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/598/personal-productivity) and ask yourself. If you can find a reference to a notable claim it could even be on topic for [Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/).

Last option would be turning it into a blog post, as I'm sure you've already guessed. It's not a question that will be deleted soon, if you are worrying about that (although I'm only speaking for myself here).

Comment: I believe the question already does require a unique perspective from developers. The best answer for a software developer is to get away from the computer and do something physical, however it should be something simple enough that you can do it mindlessly and it won't take your thoughts away from what you are doing. I very much doubt that this is the answer for all other professions, or even a large number of other professions.

Comment: However you do make a good point about the question asking for a list of opinions and experiences. I wrote this question back when it was recommended that questions invite sharing experiences. I have edited my question so that it focuses more on getting a single answer than a list of opinions/experiences. Please consider re-opening it.

Comment: `The best answer for a software developer is to get away from the computer and do something physical` Which is the same answer for every professional working with a computer... How does that make it unique to software developers? (and I'm on my WorkRave rest break right now)

Comment: The 2nd part of that is `something simple enough that you can do it mindlessly and it won't take your thoughts away from what you are doing`. I feel this is unique to developers. Most computer-related jobs will recommend frequent breaks from the computer, however they encourage you to take your mind off your work, not stay focused on it. I know when I worked as a receptionist or in other clerical positions, I escaped my work whenever I could while on breaks.

Comment: We are not the unique snowflakes you seem to think we are... The advice is the same for every creative desk job, the question is blatantly off topic.

Comment: I would further say that not every computer-related profession recommends you take a break every 30 minutes. The majority of computer users are just that: users. They get breaks usually every 2 hours and I very rarely see someone who will stay focused on their work during their breaks. Sitting at a computer screen using an application is very different from sitting at a computer screen deep in "the zone" hammering out code.

Comment: I completely disagree with your assumptions. Off topic, possibly on topic for Personal Productivity, I'd gladly move it there if we verify that they want it - and even if _somehow_ it's slightly on topic here, it's more suitable for Personal Productivity anyway. Break ends in 30 seconds, bye for now.